# Netty 4 OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, netty, threadpoolexecutor

I can not find the OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor in Netty 4.0.7.

I am writing a demo based on Netty 4.0.7's proxy example, I am doing a file transfer from backend to frontend.

When my backend server send all the bytes to proxy, the server will FIN the connection;

I found that when the speed of frontend network is slower than backend network, the backend channelInActive() triggered before all the read event of backend is processed, I can not find a way to make sure the close event is always triggered after all the read event done.

I think the OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor in Netty 3.x maybe doing this, but I can not find it in Netty 4, then how Netty 4 ensure the event process order?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just use a custom EventExecutor when adding the handler in the ChannelPipeline.

See 
http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy.html#wiki-h2-32

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I want to make sure the close event form backend is processed at last although it comes first, before some of the read event.  Will OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor be the best choice? Does Netty has a way to put close event specially ad the end of the event queue?

Comment: You can close the Channel in the ChannelFutureListener added to a ChannelFuture of an operation. Is this what you want ?

Comment: So, in that ChannelFuture operation, do I have a way to check if all the pending MessageEvents on the current chennel have finished? Then I could close the channel if they are all done.

Comment: For this you need to write an empty ChannelBuffer to the Channel and add a listener to it. Once this is noticed you know everything is written